# Ifconfig goes to uninterruptible sleep state and same process is invoked multiple time with different pid

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am using system() command to run my script which inturn calls "ifconfig eth0 | grep \" RUNNING\"".  Seems ifconfig is not responding and my system call blocks on it which moves my script to interruptible sleep state. Why am i seeing my script called multiple times after it goes to S state?

```
7514 sh z
7515 ifonfig D
7576 sh           S
7577 ifconfig_script.sh S
7705 ifconfig_script.sh S
7706 ifconfig D
7707 grep S
7720 sh S
7721 ifconfig_script.sh S
7795 ifconfig_script.sh S
7796 ifconfig D
7797 grep S
7820 sh S
7821 ifconfig_script.sh S
7895 ifconfig_script.sh S
7896 ifconfig D
7897 grep S
........
........
........
........
```

Can anyone help me why i seeing same process called multiple times with different pid?

Comment: Did you terminate all of your jammed scripts or are they still stuck?

Comment: As an aside, ifconfig has been deprecated on linux for quite awhile.  I think it was last updated over 15 years ago.

Comment: @tadman No..it lead to memleak and my system reboots.

Answer (score 1):

did you run script more than one time?

and what is the result of running `ifconfig eth0` in shell?

it looks like a zombie process in the way

```
7514 sh z
```

the smallest pid indicates that maybe  first call ifconfig was blocked ,

and the zombie process blocked  the latter call

Comment: I ran it only once.

I got nothing from ifconfig etho, seems ifconfig is not reaponding

Does zombies block other calls ?

Comment: if you ran script  only once, it is unusual to have more than one instance of  ifconfig_script.sh

post your simplified script here may help us understand the situation more clearly

Comment: Is there a way kernel brings up the sleeping process multiple times ?